# Magento 2: How to upload the product images from Gallery?

Tags: magento2, product-images

I have bulk images for product, so I have added those images to Gallery but in the product page in admin panel, I cannot see an option to choose the product images from Gallery.

[image]

How can I allow the admins to choose the images from gallery for products?

Any help will be appreciated!